# How keep showing jQuery Mobile spinner beyond page-loading-end?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Once page loading is complete in `jQuery Mobile`, the **spinner** disappears. I want the spinner to stay until after some event (data arrival from server):

```
$('#form').live('pagebeforeshow', function(){
   var def = $.Deferred();

   $.post('url', obj)
      .success(function (response) {
         def.resolve();
      });

   def.done(function(){
      // I want the spinner to disappear now.
   });
});
// in this point, once the 'pagebeforeshow' handler is returned,
// the spinner disappears - but I want it to stay only after def is resolved.
```

(b.t.w. I guess it'd be simpler to locate the point where the spinner is removed, and redisplay it just right after that.. I hope to find a more elegant solution that won't have that risk (although small risk, but still..) of having that kind of flicker)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.mobile.loading( 'show')` on `$('#form').live('pageshow', function()` and when the event completes and you can use `.mobile.loading( 'hide')`.